# Is there a shorter way to write Ember computed/get method?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ecmascript-6

Is there a short way to write the code below (from *Rock & Roll with Ember.js* book):

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  noSongs: Ember.computed('model.songs.length', function() {
    return this.get('model.songs.length') === 0;
  }),
  (...)
});
```

I reckon I can desctructure import for `Controller`, `get` and `computed`:

```
import { Controller, get, computed } from 'ember';
```

#### Questions

- Can I use arrow function inside the `computed` instead of `function`?
- Is there a more javascript-ish way to do `this.get('model.songs.length')` as it feels awkward to have `length` as a string?

Comment: `noSongs: Ember.computed.eq('model.songs.length', 0),`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I reckon I can desctructure import for `Controller`, `get` and `computed`:

You can use the new Modules API, detailed in the [2.16 release blog post](https://emberjs.com/blog/2017/10/11/ember-2-16-released.html#toc_ember-js-modules-api).

> Can I use arrow function inside the `computed` instead of `function`?

No, because the context of that arrow function will actually be the surrounding module, and not the object. Notice that `Ember.Controller.extend` receives an object as an argument, not a function, and that it is not the `class` syntax that ES2015 introduced.

> Is there a more javascript-ish way to do `this.get('model.songs.length')` as it feels awkward to have length as a string?

Length is not a string, it's a property of the `model.songs` array that should have a numeric value. You should use `.get` in Ember objects or you won't be able to retrieve computed properties.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use arrow function inside the computed instead of function?

No you can't.

> Is there a more javascript-ish way to do
>   this.get('model.songs.length') as it feels awkward to have length as a
>   string?

IMHO this looks ok.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the `arrow` function, reading the [No binding of `this` section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this) seems to indicate we will use the `Ember.Controller` context

Comment: @ÉdouardLopez you are passing an object to `extend` when you do `Ember.Controller.extend({})`. That means the context for `this` is the module. By the ES2015 specification, `this` in a module is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use arrow function inside the computed instead of function?

The function you are passing as the second argument to the `computed()` method is used down in the guts of Ember as a property in the creation of Ember property descriptor object. When it is invoked later (from down in the guts) Ember tries to assign it the proper context (in this case your Controller) but arrow functions don't support being invoked with a context so they will just run in the context of wherever they are invoked from.

> Is there a more javascript-ish way to do this.get('model.songs.length') as it feels awkward to have length as a string?

That's Ember. After you've used it eleventy million times it will feel natural.